# Unable to change default download directory for google chrome while downloading using Selenium - python

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to download a file from a URL using Selenium in Python.
I'm trying to change the default download directory using *Options*

The script runs without any error message, but the download directory doesn't get updated.
I'm using a jupyter notebook on Windows.
This is what my code looks like:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\danish.zahid\Downloads\pubsmed\\",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
})
# specify the title of the study you want to download
study_title = "Pan-cancer single-cell landscape of tumor-infiltrating T cells"
# start the browser and navigate to the PubMed website
s = Service(r"C:\Users\danish.zahid\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
browser.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")
# find the search box, enter the study title, and submit the form
search_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "id_term")
search_box.send_keys(study_title)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# find the save button to and click it
save_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='save-results-panel-trigger']")
save_button.click()
# Select Pubmed from drop down
dropdownlist  = browser.find_element(By.ID, "save-action-format")
select_dropdown = Select(dropdownlist)
select_dropdown.select_by_visible_text("PubMed")
download_file = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='save-action-panel-form']/div[2]/button[1]")
download_file.click()
browser.quit()
```

Went through a lot of possible solutions online but cant seem to make it work what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: seems you have extra backlash  at the end of your defined directory. try removing them:
`
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\danish.zahid\Downloads\pubsmed\\",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
})
`
also, check the directory permissions too.

Comment: I just tried to run it without browser.close(), and it worked. Is there any way i could put a lag before the browser.close() runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, my friend

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": "C:\\Users\\PC\\OneDrive\\Documents\\",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
})
# specify the title of the study you want to download
study_title = "Pan-cancer single-cell landscape of tumor-infiltrating T cells"
# start the browser and navigate to the PubMed website

browser = Chrome(options=options)
browser.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")
# find the search box, enter the study title, and submit the form
search_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, "id_term")
search_box.send_keys(study_title)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# # find the save button to and click it
save_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='save-results-panel-trigger']")
save_button.click()
# # Select Pubmed from drop-down
dropdownlist  = browser.find_element(By.ID, "save-action-format")
dropdownlist.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'option[value="pmid"]').click()
download_file = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='save-action-panel-form']/div[2]/button[1]")
download_file.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

As you can see, the target file "**pmid-34914499.txt**" will get downloaded on the mentioned path "C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\", which is inside the Documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

First modify your add_experimental_option:

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\danish.zahid\Downloads\pubsmed"),
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
})
```

for adding wait time also, you can use `time.sleep(10)` after `download_file.click()`